# Why does the decimal representation of (10^x * 10^y) always suffix the same representation in binary?

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

```
10d * 10d = 100d ~ (100 in decimal) - last three digits of result are 100
100d =  1100100b ~ (100 in binary)  - last three digits of result are 100
```

If you multiply any (10^x * 10^y) together, you always get the decimal result at the end of the binary result ...

```
1000d * 100d =       100000d - last 6 digits are 100000
100000d = 11000011010100000b - last 6 digits are 100000
```

...

```
1000000d * 10000000d =                          10000000000000d
10000000000000d = 10010001100001001110011100101010000000000000b
```

... i think you get the idea by now!!

Comment: The short version: $10$ is a multiple of $2$, but not of $2^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at powers of ten:

$10^n = 5^n \times 2^n$

so $10^n$ is $1$ followed by $n$ $0$s in decimal

and $2^n$ is $1$ followed by $n$ $0$s in binary

while $5^n$ (being odd) ends with a $1$ in binary

so $10^n$ ends with exactly $n$ $0$s in binary

Comment: What you said :0)

Answer (score 0):

Just worked 1t 0ut ...

it's because `10d` is `1010b`

so every time you multiply `1010b` by a multiple of itself, you can forget the first two digits, and just pretend you're multiplying `10d * 10d`.